# How can I securely hang a hammock on trailer framing?

Tags: furniture

I want to hang a hammock indoors, but my trailer has dry wall ceilings and walls, you know, thin trailer walls. I am scared that it will not be able to hold my weight in the hammock, since I weigh 148 lbs.

Also I believe the wall would be too flimsy to keep the screw in it. Any advice or tips? Or better ways of setting up a hammock to where it won't collapse, or where I don't have to use a screw?

Comment: When you say trailer, do you mean a trailer home, or a towing trailer?

Comment: Use a hammock stand.    trailer walls and ceilings won’t hold up to the stress a hammock will exert

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Double-Hammock-Saving-Include-Carrying/dp/B01HAS6Q48

Comment: Are you willing and able to drill a hole completely through the wall to the outside?

Comment: @kris put your 2 comments together as an answer, I think we all agree trailers probably won’t support even the op’s light body.

Comment: Please describe your "trailer" in more detail so we're talking about the same thing here. Is it an RV or a mobile home?

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid a trailer is not structurally able to support a hammock even for a small person. . Not from the ceiling and not from walls.

The  solution is a hammock stand.

[image]

These are readily available online.

Answer (score 0):

In a regular house you could just screw into studs. Just a simple eyebolt into a stud on each end should hold you. I'm uncertain what's behind your walls, though, as "trailer" covers a large variety of construction techniques, many of them more concerned with cost than strength. With that in mind, unless you know how your walls are constructed, I would recommend a stand.

Answer (score 0):

Many trailers (such as RV campers) are constructed with 2x2 wood studs sandwiched between the aluminum skin and some interior wallboard (usually 1/4" paneling). I believe that these would hold your weight (perhaps with some flex), but you must use suitable anchors.

If you can reliably set 3/8" lag screw eyebolts to a depth of at least 1", properly piloted, they won't pull out at your weight. You'd want to pilot with a 3/16" bit marked for depth (1" plus the thickness of the wallboard).

Try to avoid hanging at the center of long walls where no intersecting walls lend support. Points near wall and ceiling corners will be most stable. Once the hammock is in place, load it slowly and observe any movement or sound that could indicate failure. Leave adequate sag in the hammock, as the straighter it is the more tension it places on the walls and hardware.